# Problem with AMD integrated gpu on new Lenovo laptop

Tags: arch-linux, gpu, amd-graphics, opengl

I recently bought a new Lenovo Ideapad Slim 3 laptop and I am having problems getting the amdgpu driver working properly in Arch Linux. The GPU seems to work fine straight away with a Mint live USB (`glxgears` plays, etc.); however, in the Arch system I am trying to install to the SSD, I get this error with `glxinfo -B`:

```
$ glxinfo -B
name of display: :0
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  151 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  37
  Current serial number in output stream:  38
```

I can't see any errors in the `dmesg` log relating to [drm] and amdgpu - the messages in Arch seem very similar to those in Mint. However, in Arch I see the following error in my `Xorg.0.log` file:

```
[    42.568] (II) Loading sub module "glamoregl"
[    42.568] (II) LoadModule: "glamoregl"
[    42.568] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so
[    42.572] (II) Module glamoregl: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    42.572]    compiled for 1.21.1.8, module version = 1.0.1
[    42.572]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    42.577] (EE) AMDGPU(0): eglGetDisplay() failed
[    42.577] (EE) AMDGPU(0): glamor detected, failed to initialize EGL.
[    42.577] (WW) AMDGPU(0): amdgpu_glamor_pre_init returned FALSE, using ShadowFB
```

The `Xorg.0.log` file for the Mint live USB doesn't show this error:

```
[    17.992] (II) Loading sub module "glamoregl"
[    17.992] (II) LoadModule: "glamoregl"
[    17.992] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so
[    17.995] (II) Module glamoregl: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    17.995]    compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 1.0.1
[    17.995]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    18.028] (II) AMDGPU(0): glamor X acceleration enabled on AMD RENOIR (LLVM 13.0.1, DRM 3.42, 5.15.0-56-generic)
[    18.028] (II) AMDGPU(0): glamor detected, initialising EGL layer.
```

It seems likely this error is related to what is causing the problem. Does anyone know what might be causing this issue between amdgpu and glamor in Arch?

It's a brand new laptop, with an AMD Ryzen 5 7530U CPU, with integrated Radeon graphics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to resolve the issue myself. The Arch system was copied over from a previous machine that had an NVidia GPU, and there were some graphics packages still installed relating to NVidia. I removed those and now the 3D acceleration seems to be working properly (both `glxinfo` and `glxgears` work). The old NVidia packages were:

```
nvidia-340xx-dkms
nvidia-340xx-utils
opencl-nvidia-340xx
xf86-video-nouveau
ffnvcodec-headers
```

Hopefully this info might help, if someone else has a similar problem in future.